# How to test power output of an 8.5kW generator?

Tags: generator

I found a very cheap 8.5 kW AC generator which works on gasoline. Produces 220 V, 380 V and 12 V as output. Some people online say is fake and it can't have 8.5 kW, that it actually has 2 kW and the label is wrong. The seller assures me that he run a 7 kW industrial welder with it and works fine. The seller is also incentivized to lie or exaggerate.

I plan to go and test this generator myself. Trouble is, it's unwieldy to carry all this loads with me required for reaching a 8.5 kW consumption or close to that. I have a 2.3 kW motor, the motor is heavy, requires me to cut something like a tree trunk to know for sure, I have a big room heater rated for 2 kW but i only have 1. So basically i need to take my 3 angle grinders, my motor, my room heater, and maybe 2 other hair driers, move them 200 km away, then put them under load, just to test this :)) Sounds like a big complicated mess. And if I go there and ask the seller to bring all this devices to generate so much load, that's something he might not be supper happy about. I would like this to depend on me.

Is there a better way to add a lot of load?

What is that simple test one can do with ease and find out how good is a random generator?

Then I've been thinking about electrolysis. I can simply drill 2 plates of steel 20 cm by 20 cm, put them in a plastic water container, and let electrolysis draw power while the generator runs. Then using a multi-meter I can check the amperage. The voltage meter already exists on the generator.

Is this something which is likely to work? How big the electrolysis plates need to be for this to draw 8.5 kW of power?
Is there some other easy way to do this?

Comment: You generally get what you pay for. Do you use on-line gambling sites?

Comment: Ask your freinds for there electric bar heaters. For a 240V areas its common for them to be rated at 1800-2400W each. Plug them in. Turn them to max and see if the voltage starts dropping.

Comment: Buy 6 of these - https://www.amazon.com/Simply-Silver-Stainless-1350W-110V-Immersion/dp/B0769HDZRL/ref=sr_1_6?dchild=1&keywords=water+heating+rod&qid=1589183606&sr=8-6

Comment: @Andy aka Im trying to not gamble very much :))

Comment: What is the weight of the generator? If it is much less than 200 lbs (90 kg), they are probably exaggerating.

Comment: 2kw heaters can be picked up very cheaply if you can't borrow any.

Comment: @Alon perhaps you should get the model number and look up the specs for it.  Keep in mind that there are 2 power ratings (and perhaps more).  One is the limit of peak power that it can put out for a short time.  The other is the limit of constant power that it can put out continuously.  Perhaps 8.5kW is the peak output and 2kW is the constant output.  Get the model and look up the specs.

Answer (score 8):

Borrow some electric kettles from your friends, or buy a couple, they're not that expensive.

They're compact, and light when empty.

They have a very predictable current draw, not something that could be said for welders or angle grinders for instance. The power factor is unity, and there's no inrush current, so there will be no argument with the vendor that you're testing the generator under ideal loading conditions.

You need only three 3 kW kettles to get to up to 9 kW. See if you can get one or two lower power ones as well, so you can adjust your load finely to see what collapses the generator output.

Comment: If the generator does 3 phase power, the load should use all three phases too. So one kettle should be connected to each phase. Be carefull to connect them to 220 V in wye or star circuit, not to 380 V in delta.